# Comparing std::string and C-style string literals

Tags: c++, comparison, c-strings, stdstring, std

Suppose I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std; // or std::

int main()
{
    string s1{ "Apple" };
    cout << boolalpha;
    cout << (s1 == "Apple") << endl; //true
}
```

My question is: How does the system check between these two? `s1` is an object while `"Apple"` is a *C-style string* literal.

As far as I know, different data types cannot be compared. What am I missing here?

Comment: [basic_string/operator_cmp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) ((7) in your case).

Comment: Fwiw, as long as one type can be converted to another, you can generally compare them.  You can initialize a `std::string` from a c-string.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is because of the following [compare operator defined for `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp)

```
template< class CharT, class Traits, class Alloc >
bool operator==( const basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>& lhs, const CharT* rhs );  // Overload (7)
```

This allows the comparison between `std::string` and the `const char*`. Thus the magic!

---

Stealing the *[@Pete Becker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1593860/pete-becker)* 's comment:

> "For completeness, if this overload did not exist, the comparison
>   would still work; The compiler would construct a temporary object of
>   type `std::string` from the *C-style string* and compare the two
>   `std::string` objects, using [the first overload of
>   `operator==`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp)
>
> ```
> template< class CharT, class Traits, class Alloc >
> bool operator==( const basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>& lhs,
>                  const basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>& rhs );   // Overload (1)
> ```
>
> Which is why this operator(i.e. *overload 7*) is there: it eliminates
>   the need for that temporary object and the overhead involved in
>   creating and destroying it."

Comment: And, for completeness, if this overload didn't exist, the comparison would still work; the compiler would construct a temporary object of type `std::string from the C-style string and compare the two `std::string objects. Which is why this operator is there: it eliminates the need for that temporary object and the overhead involved in creating and destroying it.

Comment: @PeteBecker Of course, I have added it to the answer. Thanks for pointing out!